# How can I `require` SASS with Angular-Cli?

Tags: angular, webpack, sass, angular-cli

According to [this](https://github.com/gdi2290/angular-starter/wiki/How-to-use-css-chunks-integration), `require` can be used at the component level to split css into chunks.

However, the following works when using `ng serve`, but not when using `ng serve --prod`.

```
import { Component, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styles: [require('./app.component.scss')],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'my-app';
}
```

The CSS is not loaded in at all when given the prod flag. Is this a bug, or is there something that I'm missing?

Comment: Is there any reason for not using `styleUrls` instead?

Comment: I want to have the css output in a chunk, as the link included says I can. The css file I want to include here is big, so I don't want it bundled with the JS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So for anyone who might stumble upon this, I found that `require` just doesn't work properly without creating a manual Webpack configuration. I didn't want to do that, so here's what I did instead:

Under `styles` in the Angular-CLI JSON, I added my SASS with a defined input and output, so that the Angular-CLI would still compile my SASS, but not bundle it.

```
"styles": [
  {
    "input": "scss/style.scss",
    "output": "assets/style/style"
  }
]
```

Then I went old school and simply added a link tag to the output csss in my index.html.

I found that since the prod build adds hashing to the CSS, the link wouldn't work, so I also needed to build with Output Hashing set to media only so that i could just link to the CSS.

```
ng build --prod --output-hashing=media
```

Thanks to @Kevin for pointing out what flags are set with the prod flag.

Answer (score 1):

These are the default flags that are set for ng serve and ng serve --prod respectively

```
Flag                 --dev      --prod
--aot                false      true
--environment        dev        prod
--output-hashing     media      all
--sourcemaps         true       false
--extract-css        false      true
```

Using ng serve --prod --extract-css=false could do the trick assuming the extract-css= true is what's breaking your require on the css file

Comment: thanks. The `--extract-css=false` didn't change anything, but `--aot=false` did... but I don't want to miss out on the aot optimization. So I guess I need to look more into what the aot compile is doing with my required Sass.